# Verificar se número está disponível dentro de um intervalo definido

Tags: php

Tenho uma numeração pré-definida, por exemplo de 1 a 4.

Agora preciso que ele mostre os números que não estão sendo usados, que seriam:

```
Números não usados: 2,4
```

Comecei o código assim:

```
<?php 
$numeros_sorteio="1,2,3,4";
$numeros_usados="1,3";

echo "numeros livres: 2,4";

?>
```

Alguém poderia me dar uma orientação de como continuar?

Comment: O que é esse pouco de PHP que sabe? Com ele, você conseguiu ao menos tentar alguma coisa?

Comment: Aliás, seja bem-vindo ao site. Busque fazer o [tour], acessar a [help] e ler o guia de [ask] para se orientar com o básico do funcionamento do site. Se restar-lhe alguma dúvida, pode frequentar o [meta].

Comment: Ola peço desculpas aos colegas se perguntei errado peço caricadamente nao me negativar edito a pergunta se for o caso estou começando agora  mil desculpas ai consertando a pergunta

Comment: A vontade :D Todas as ações aqui no site são reversíveis. O voto negativo é só uma forma de mostrar que há algo errado na sua pergunta, tanto que a descrição no botão é "esta pergunta não mostra nenhum esforço de pesquisa; ela não é clara ou não é útil". Você pode editá-la e se ficar dentro dos padrões, quem votou negativamente poderá rever o voto, retirando o voto negativo e até dando o positivo.

Comment: Obrigado entendi vamo que vamo editei ai sera que ficou legal digo mais claro ?

Comment: Vou te passar a lógica para estudar: Criar um `array` com os números listados e outro com com livres, então tu deve percorrer este `array` com um `for` e comparar um com o outro usando um `if`. Obs.: Em PHP existe a comparação de `==` (igual) e `===` (idêntico), por exemplo: `1 == "1"`, Isto quer dizer que os valores são iguais, mas não idênticos (veja que são de tipos diferentes), já `1 === 1` são iguais e idênticos.

Answer (score 2):

O ideal é converter essas duas strings em dois arrays com `explode()`, dessa forma pode obter a diferença (o elementos de `$todos` que não estão em `$disponiveis`) com a função `array_diff()`

```
$todos = explode(',', '1,2,3,4');
$usados = explode(',','1,3');

$disponiveis = array_diff($todos, $usados);
echo 'Números disponiveis: '. implode(',', $disponiveis);
```

Comment: Perfeito deu certo Obrigado ai a todos muito obrigado mesmo !